transferring information between panels using custom events
In modern wxwidgets using c++, I am trying to transfer information between two wxPanels using a custom event - but it seems I just can't get it right. I get various compiler errors, that I don't understand. Any help would be most appreciated.
I define the custom event:
// CustomEvents.h
#ifndef CUSTOM_EVENTS_H
#define CUSTOM_EVENTS_H

#include <wx/wx.h>

// Define a new event type
wxDECLARE_EVENT(EVT_CUSTOM_DATA, wxCommandEvent);

// Custom event class
class CustomEvent : public wxCommandEvent {
public:
    CustomEvent(wxEventType eventType = EVT_CUSTOM_DATA, int id = 0);
    CustomEvent(const CustomEvent& event);
    wxEvent* Clone() const override;

    // Setters and Getters for the custom data
    void SetData(const wxString& data);
    wxString GetData() const;

private:
    wxString m_data;
};

#endif // CUSTOM_EVENTS_H

and
#include "MyCustomEvent.h"

CustomEvent::CustomEvent(wxEventType eventType, int id )
    : wxCommandEvent(eventType, id) 
{
}

CustomEvent::CustomEvent(const CustomEvent& event) : wxCommandEvent(event) 
{
}

wxEvent* CustomEvent::Clone() const 
{ 
    return new CustomEvent(*this); 
}

// Setters and Getters for the custom data
void CustomEvent::SetData(const wxString& data) 
{ 
    m_data = data; 
}

wxString CustomEvent::GetData() const 
{ 
    return m_data; 
}

wxDEFINE_EVENT(EVT_CUSTOM_DATA, wxCommandEvent);

And then I define the two panels.
Panel1.h:
// Panel1.h
#ifndef PANEL1_H
#define PANEL1_H

#include <wx/wx.h>
#include "MyCustomEvent.h"

class Panel1 : public wxPanel {
public:
    Panel1(wxWindow* parent);

private:
    void OnButtonClicked(wxCommandEvent& event);

    wxButton* m_button;
    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};

#endif // PANEL1_H

Panel1.cpp:
// Panel1.cpp

#include "Panel1.h"    

Panel1::Panel1(wxWindow* parent)
    : wxPanel(parent) {
    m_button = new wxButton(this, wxID_ANY, "Send Data");
    
    m_button->Bind(EVT_CUSTOM_DATA, &Panel1::OnButtonClicked, this);
}

void Panel1::OnButtonClicked(wxCommandEvent& event) {
    CustomEvent customEvent(EVT_CUSTOM_DATA);
    customEvent.SetData("Hello from Panel1");
    wxPostEvent(GetParent(), customEvent); // Post event to the parent window
}

Panel2.h:
// Panel2.h
#ifndef PANEL2_H
#define PANEL2_H

#include <wx/wx.h>
#include "MyCustomEvent.h"

class Panel2 : public wxPanel {
public:
    Panel2(wxWindow* parent);

    void OnCustomDataReceived(wxCommandEvent& event);

private:
    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};

#endif // PANEL2_H

Panel2.cpp
// Panel2.cpp
#include "Panel2.h"
#include <wx/stattext.h>


Panel2::Panel2(wxWindow* parent)
    : wxPanel(parent) 
{
    new wxStaticText(this, wxID_ANY, "Waiting for data...");
    Bind(EVT_CUSTOM_DATA, &Panel2::OnCustomDataReceived, this);
}

void Panel2::OnCustomDataReceived(wxCommandEvent& event) {
    wxStaticText* label = dynamic_cast<wxStaticText*>(FindWindowById(wxID_ANY));
    if (label) 
    {
        label->SetLabel(event.GetString()); // Update label with the received data
    }
}

And then finally, I define the main frame and the app:
// MainFrame.h
#ifndef MAINFRAME_H
#define MAINFRAME_H

#include <wx/wx.h>
#include "Panel1.h"
#include "Panel2.h"

class MainFrame : public wxFrame {
public:
    MainFrame();

private:
    Panel1* m_panel1;
    Panel2* m_panel2;
};

#endif // MAINFRAME_H

and
// MainFrame.cpp
#include "MainFrame.h"
#include <wx/sizer.h>

MainFrame::MainFrame()
    : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, "Custom Event Example") {
    wxBoxSizer* sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);

    m_panel1 = new Panel1(this);
    m_panel2 = new Panel2(this);

    sizer->Add(m_panel1, 1, wxEXPAND);
    sizer->Add(m_panel2, 1, wxEXPAND);

    SetSizer(sizer);
    SetSize(800, 600);
}

and here's the main app:
// MainApp.h
#ifndef MAINAPP_H
#define MAINAPP_H

#include <wx/wx.h>

class MainApp : public wxApp {
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

#endif // MAINAPP_H

and source file of the main app:
// MainApp.cpp

#include "MainApp.h"
#include "MainFrame.h"

bool MainApp::OnInit() {
    MainFrame* frame = new MainFrame();
    frame->Show(true);
    return true;
}

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MainApp);

Running the code above in ms visual studio 2022,i get the following linker compiler errors:
Unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual struct wxEventTable const* __cdecl Panel1::GetEventTable@Panel1@@MEBAPEBUwxEventTable@@XZ)

Unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual class wxEventHashTable & __cdecl Panel1::GetEventHashTable(void)const " (? GetEventHashTable@Panel1@@MEBAAEAVwxEventHashTabke@@XZ)

Unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual struct wxEventTable const* __cdecl Panel2::GetEventTable@Panel2@@MEBAPEBUwxEventTable@@XZ)

Unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual class wxEventHashTable & __cdecl Panel2::GetEventHashTable(void)const " (? GetEventHashTable@Panel2@@MEBAAEAVwxEventHashTabke@@XZ)


Regarding your question, you should actually post the full compiler error output in the question. Otherwise it'll be hard to answer what the errors mean.

Thanks. I now added the full compiler errors.

Those are not compilation errors. Those are linking errors. You need to link with the wx librariy/libraries.

But, at least as far as I can tell, the wx libraries are included. If I run other programs that do not include a custom event - or, alternatively, if I remove the custom event from the current program - everything runs properly.

Ok, so are the missing member functions in Panel1 and Panel2 (GetEventTable and GetEventHashTable) something you declared in your header file but did not define?

No, I'm guessing they are included automatically in wxwidget's handling of the custom event. These are not functions that I define or declared anywhere in my code, as you can see.

Then you most probably not linking with all the wx libraries that are needed. Try adding all of them just to see if the problem goes away.

If you have Declare_X in a class header then you need Implement_X in the cpp file, those macros come in pairs.

For even tables you have a pair of begin and end https://docs.wxwidgets.org/latest/group__group__funcmacro__events.html#ga736930efaab4d7e445e9e8e520c7b74d but if you don't need them then you don't need to declare an event table in the header

@RonenChriki, did you look at the docs? Did you check the event sample?

Right! Of course I forgot to add the begin and end event tables.
Thanks for pointing that out.

Your link errors are due to using wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE() in your panel classes. As the macro name indicates, this is a declaration — and you need a matching definition, provided by wx{BEGIN,END}_EVENT_TABLE() macros if you use it.
However in your case you don't use static event tables at all as you use Bind() instead, so the simplest, and best, solution is to just remove wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE() macros completely.
